# GUI tool for managing Docker like Kitematic

Tags: software-recommendation, docker

Is there a GUI for Docker on Ubuntu like Kitematic? (included in Docker toolbox but this only runs on Windows and Mac at the moment?)

[image]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Kitematic** is available for Ubuntu (although the website itself doesn't advertise it), you can get it from the [Github repository](https://github.com/docker/kitematic/releases).
Simply extract the downloaded file and install it with your favorite package manager.

Comment: To save future readers one click, this tool is archived and the authors suggest using Docker Desktop instead.

Comment: Deprecated project. The official manger (Docker Desktop) is now available in Linux:
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/install/

Answer (score 18):

If you already have docker installed, Portainer does a good job on this.
It runs in a light-weight docker container itself. It's open source and exposing a webinterface.

Just run:

```
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 \  
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \  
portainer/portainer
```

And point your browser to http://localhost:9000.
Check out some more background at [Portainer](https://portainer.io/).

Answer (score 17):

You can try 
[DockStation](https://dockstation.io) too.

It's [free](https://dockstation.io/#price) for personal and commercial purposes and [available](https://github.com/DockStation/dockstation/releases) for Linux, macOS & Windows. There is an AppImages for Linux too.

[DockStation Screenshots](https://dockstation.io/#screenshots)

Answer (score 8):

[This site is very useful for finding alternative software](http://alternativeto.net/software/kitematic/) for anything (`!alt docker gui` in duckduckgo for a quick search of it). The top rated alternative right now is [Rancher](http://rancher.com/) but I greatly prefer [Dockstation](https://dockstation.io/)

Answer (score 1):

[Cockpit](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/cockpit) is available on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and there is a docker module as well.  Once I got `cockpit-ws` installed and running, I was able to download and launch containers easily.

Answer (score 1):

if you choose to download Kitematic for ubuntu; Make sure that the user running kitematic belongs to group docker.

Answer (score 0):

For current users like me on Ubuntu 21.04 these answers are dated and should be annotated such like:

- Kitematic : is now archived. But if like me you tried to install on 21.04
  it wont work as the dependencies have be deprecated.
- Dockstation : didn't work for me and I don't want to spend hours trying to find out why and maybe not being able to fix.

So I tried Portainer and it works with little fuss so I would recommend this. But its not the latest version and I need to do some work...